# Network policy not working for daemonsets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have a kubernetes cluster in IBM cloud which has a daemonset and backend pods. I had setup a network policy where backend service can accept daemonset requests. But the daemonset shows `Connection Refused` error when sending requests to backend pods.
Any idea?

Daemonset yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ds-network-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      component: ds
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

Backend yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: backend-network-policy
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          component: ds
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      component: backend
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

Comment: Have you got any error messages to share?

Comment: Please share your yamls.

Comment: and some information about the CNI setup being used.

Comment: I have modified the post

Comment: Could you share 'daemonset' and 'backend' PODs definition?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? Is network policy also applicable to daemonset?